# Is there still a content dispute on this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, locked-posts

I was browsing the list of [locked posts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=locked%3a1%20migrated%3a0) and noticed this one: [Is Harry related to Ginny by blood?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120995/is-harry-related-to-ginny-by-blood)

The question had [multiple edits](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/120995/revisions) and was eventually locked, with a notice of a content dispute. That was 17 days ago. Does it still need to be locked?

Comment: I just realized that the timing of my post coincides with another question about a post that has a content dispute...

Comment: Wow, that's quite the mess. OP writes a question asking if Harry and Ginny are related, gets a good answer, gets closed as a dupe, changes it to asking who all of Harry's relatives are and claims that's what he always meant to ask yet also claiming this does not invalidate the answer even though it very blatantly does, then it gets reopened (why!?) then re-closed as too broad post-edit because it is too broad...I do not envy the mods who have to deal with this.

Comment: @Ixrec I'm just hoping that whatever dispute there was has blown over in the last 17 days. The OP has asked plenty of questions since then, but none seem related to that post, so I don't know if he cares anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've unlocked it, since as you say it's been a while and hopefully there's no longer a content dispute.

If the edit war resumes, please flag the post for mod attention.

Comment: Unlocked, but still a dupe.

Comment: Thanks. Do locks time out on their own? I thought maybe this question had been forgotten about, but if I knew the lock was going to expire by itself, I wouldn't have said anything.

Comment: @anaranjada Some do, some don't. I believe the expiry date isn't visible to non-mods though (e.g. can you see any difference between the lock on hedgehog's Dementors question and the lock on this one?)

Comment: No, they both just say "Post Locked."